# Kmeans Euclidean Distance to Each Centroid Avoid Splitting Features From Rest of DF

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, k-means

I have a df:

```
    id      Type1   Type2   Type3   
0   10000   0.0     0.00    0.00    
1   10001   0.0     63.72   0.00    
2   10002   473.6   174.00  31.60   
3   10003   0.0     996.00  160.92  
4   10004   0.0     524.91  0.00
```

I apply k-means to this df and add the resulting cluster to the df:

```
kmeans = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=5, random_state=0).fit(df.drop('id', axis=1))
df['cluster'] = kmeans.labels_
```

Now I'm attempting to add columns to the df for the Euclidean distance between each point (i.e. row in the df) and each centroid:

```
def distance_to_centroid(row, centroid):
    row = row[['Type1',
               'Type2',
               'Type3']]
    return euclidean(row, centroid)

df['distance_to_center_0'] = df.apply(lambda r: distance_to_centroid(r, kmeans.cluster_centers_[0]),1)
```

This results in this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-56fa3ae3df54> in <module>()
----> 1 df['distance_to_center_0'] = df.apply(lambda r: distance_to_centroid(r, kmeans.cluster_centers_[0]),1)

~\_installed\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, result_type, args, **kwds)
   6002                          args=args,
   6003                          kwds=kwds)
-> 6004         return op.get_result()
   6005 
   6006     def applymap(self, func):

~\_installed\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in get_result(self)
    140             return self.apply_raw()
    141 
--> 142         return self.apply_standard()
    143 
    144     def apply_empty_result(self):

~\_installed\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply_standard(self)
    246 
    247         # compute the result using the series generator
--> 248         self.apply_series_generator()
    249 
    250         # wrap results

~\_installed\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply_series_generator(self)
    275             try:
    276                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
--> 277                     results[i] = self.f(v)
    278                     keys.append(v.name)
    279             except Exception as e:

<ipython-input-34-56fa3ae3df54> in <lambda>(r)
----> 1 df['distance_to_center_0'] = df.apply(lambda r: distance_to_centroid(r, kmeans.cluster_centers_[0]),1)

<ipython-input-33-7b988ca2ad8c> in distance_to_centroid(row, centroid)
      7                 'atype',
      8                 'anothertype']]
----> 9     return euclidean(row, centroid)

~\_installed\anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\distance.py in euclidean(u, v, w)
    596 
    597     """
--> 598     return minkowski(u, v, p=2, w=w)
    599 
    600 

~\_installed\anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\distance.py in minkowski(u, v, p, w)
    488     if p < 1:
    489         raise ValueError("p must be at least 1")
--> 490     u_v = u - v
    491     if w is not None:
    492         w = _validate_weights(w)

ValueError: ('operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (7,) (8,) ', 'occurred at index 0')
```

This error appears to be happening because `id` is not included in the `row` variable in the function `distance_to_centroid`. To fix this, I could split the df into two parts (`id` in df1 and the rest of the columns in df2). However, this is very manual, and does not allow for easy changes of columns. Is there a way to get the distance to each centroid into the original df without splitting the original df? In the same vein, is there a better way to find the euclidean distance that wouldn't involve manually entering the columns into the `row` variable, as well as manually creating however many columns as clusters?

**Expected Result:**

```
    id      Type1   Type2   Type3   cluster    distanct_to_cluster_0
0   10000   0.0     0.00    0.00    1          2.3
1   10001   0.0     63.72   0.00    2          3.6 
2   10002   473.6   174.00  31.60   0          0.5 
3   10003   0.0     996.00  160.92  3          3.7 
4   10004   0.0     524.91  0.00    4          1.8
```

Comment: Do you want the KMeans to be fitted with `df` or with `df` without the `id` column? (In other words, shouldn't we be computing `kmeans = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=5, random_state=0).fit(df.drop('id', axis=1))`?

Comment: without, i see what you're saying - it's currently fitting it with `id`. I updated my question with your code. all the rest remains the same, I think

Comment: where are you importing euclidean from?

Comment: importing euclidean from scipy

Comment: @unutbu's solution works for me. Can you double check by reading your data again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We need to pass the coordinate-part of `df` to `KMeans`, and we want to compute the distance to the centroids with just the coordinate-part of `df`. So we might as well define a variable for this quantity:

```
points = df.drop('id', axis=1)
# or points = df[['Type1', 'Type2', 'Type3']]
```

We could then compute the distance from the coordinate-part of each row to its corresponding centroid using:

```
import scipy.spatial.distance as sdist
centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
dist = sdist.norm(points - centroids[df['cluster']])
```

Notice that `centroids[df['cluster']]` returns a NumPy array of the same shape as `points`. Indexing by `df['cluster']` "expands" the `centroids` array.

We can then assign these `dist` values to a DataFrame column using

```
df['dist'] = dist
```

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn.cluster as cluster
import scipy.spatial.distance as sdist

df = pd.DataFrame({'Type1': [0.0, 0.0, 473.6, 0.0, 0.0],
 'Type2': [0.0, 63.72, 174.0, 996.0, 524.91],
 'Type3': [0.0, 0.0, 31.6, 160.92, 0.0],
 'id': [1000, 10001, 10002, 10003, 10004]})

points = df.drop('id', axis=1)
# or points = df[['Type1', 'Type2', 'Type3']]
kmeans = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=5, random_state=0).fit(points)
df['cluster'] = kmeans.labels_

centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
dist = sdist.norm(points - centroids[df['cluster']])
df['dist'] = dist

print(df)
```

yields

```
   Type1   Type2   Type3     id  cluster          dist
0    0.0    0.00    0.00   1000        4  2.842171e-14
1    0.0   63.72    0.00  10001        2  2.842171e-14
2  473.6  174.00   31.60  10002        1  2.842171e-14
3    0.0  996.00  160.92  10003        3  2.842171e-14
4    0.0  524.91    0.00  10004        0  2.842171e-14
```

---

If you want the distances from each point to each cluster centroid, you could use [`sdist.cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html):

```
import scipy.spatial.distance as sdist
sdist.cdist(points, centroids)
```

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn.cluster as cluster
import scipy.spatial.distance as sdist

df = pd.DataFrame({'Type1': [0.0, 0.0, 473.6, 0.0, 0.0],
 'Type2': [0.0, 63.72, 174.0, 996.0, 524.91],
 'Type3': [0.0, 0.0, 31.6, 160.92, 0.0],
 'id': [1000, 10001, 10002, 10003, 10004]})

points = df.drop('id', axis=1)
# or points = df[['Type1', 'Type2', 'Type3']]
kmeans = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=5, random_state=0).fit(points)
df['cluster'] = kmeans.labels_

centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
dists = pd.DataFrame(
    sdist.cdist(points, centroids), 
    columns=['dist_{}'.format(i) for i in range(len(centroids))],
    index=df.index)
df = pd.concat([df, dists], axis=1)

print(df)
```

yields

```
   Type1   Type2   Type3     id  cluster      dist_0      dist_1        dist_2       dist_3       dist_4
0    0.0    0.00    0.00   1000        4  524.910000  505.540819  6.372000e+01  1008.915877     0.000000
1    0.0   63.72    0.00  10001        2  461.190000  487.295802  2.842171e-14   946.066195    63.720000
2  473.6  174.00   31.60  10002        1  590.282431    0.000000  4.872958e+02   957.446929   505.540819
3    0.0  996.00  160.92  10003        3  497.816266  957.446929  9.460662e+02     0.000000  1008.915877
4    0.0  524.91    0.00  10004        0    0.000000  590.282431  4.611900e+02   497.816266   524.910000
```